Microsoft Access SQL
I am looking for a solution to fill fields in an Access DB SQL statement.
Any suggestions?
Example of the dataset attached:

Goal:

I am looking for a solution to fill fields in an Access DB SQl statement.
Any suggestions?
Example of the dataset attached:
Initial situation
Goal
I'd really appreciate your help!
THX!!

As you can't sort the recordset as is, you can't use SQL.
Use VBA and DAO to loop the records and update as desired:
Public Function FillProduction()

    Dim Records     As DAO.Recordset
    
    Dim Sql         As String
    Dim Number4     As Long
    
    Sql = "Select * From YourTableName"
    Set Records = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Sql)
    
    While Not Records.EOF
        If Records.Fields("1").Value = 510 Then
            Number4 = Records.Fields("4").Value
        Else
            Records.Edit
                Records.Fields("4").Value = Number4
            Records.Update
        End If
        Records.MoveNext
    Wend
    Records.Close
    
End Function


You essentially already answered this question with near-identical code (see the duplicate). It's better to flag as a duplicate than to answer the same question again and again

@ErikA: Oh, thanks, I failed recalling my own code examples ... However, that data had a unique ID, thus could have been updated by SQL. This data hasn't and, in fact, though not knowing the context, Excel might be a better tool.

Thanks folks...works so far. but pls keep the topic open, may have some topic related other questions.

@user26078809 That's not how Stack Overflow works. If you have a related question, ask a new one, and possibly link this for context when relevant
